# How to parse raw mime content in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime

I have raw mime message which contains html content, inline images and attachments.

I want to parse and display the content in html page as like as mail client are displaying.

Is there any java library or methods available to parse the raw mime content ?

Comment: display it where? swing component? html page?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I want to display the content in html page.

Comment: What is the type of the object? Is it a MimeMessage or a String containing the message?

Comment: @BenoitWickramarachi String mime content ( The content same as show original message in gmail )

Comment: Ok, can you show us some code. How are you retrieving the message?

Comment: @BenoitWickramarachi I have txt files which contains mime message, I am not retrieving message from mail server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find mimetype of response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077933/how-to-find-mimetype-of-response)

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the file, then create a MimeMessage:

```
   // read the file
    StringBuffer fileData = new StringBuffer(1000);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(/*PATH*/)));
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
        fileData.append(buf, 0, numRead);
    }
    reader.close();



// Create a MimeMessage


Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData.toString().getBytes()));
```

Now that you have a mime message you can have access to its content using:

```
message.getContent();
```

The content type will depend on the mime type (could be a String, a Multipart object...)

Here is the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getContent%28%29) for MimeMessage.

Comment: You don't need to make a copy of the data before calling the MimeMessage constructor; just feed it the file directly, e.g., using a [SharedFileInputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/SharedFileInputStream.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read message by using `MimeMessage` and `MimeMultipart`
from

```
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
...

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(emailMessage.getBytes());

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, is);

        if (message.getContent() instanceof String) {
            return (String) message.getContent();
        }

        MimeMultipart content = (MimeMultipart)message.getContent();

        if (content.getCount() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        String contentString = (String) content.getBodyPart(0).getContent();
```