# Download mail with attachment using ews

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I have a requirement in which I need to download email and save it( as eml file) and each its attachment as separate files using java and ews managed api. After some search on internet I have written following java code, it seem to be doing what I want. However I have some doubts about its efficiency since I think in this approach each attachment is downloaded twice from remote. Is that comment correct and if its, is there a way to do this more efficiently?

```
        item.load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent,ItemSchema.Attachments));
        MimeContent mc = item.getMimeContent();
        try(FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("d:\\emailtmp\\"+ Utils.cleanFileName(item.getId().getUniqueId())+".eml");){
            fs.write(mc.getContent());
        }
        AttachmentCollection attachments = item.getAttachments();
        if(attachments == null ) 
            return ;
        for(Attachment a : attachments){
            if (a instanceof FileAttachment){
                try(FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("d:\\emailtmp\\"+Utils.cleanFileName(((FileAttachment) a).getName()));){
                    FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment)a;
                    fileAttachment.load(stream);
                }
            }
        }
```

PS:Using EWS Managed Api 2.0-Java8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attachments will be in the Mime Content so if you want to make it more efficient you should be able to reprocess the Mime Content once you download it with a Mime parser and extract the attachments from there. Also you code doesn't cater for nested attached eg attachments of attached messages etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not mention in question but we do not process attached emails and their attachments, only the first level is processed. This is why code ignore them. By the way can you post any sample code of link (sample code for loading the mimecontent from local stored object)?

Comment: Just look for a Mime library you comfortable with and work in the language your using eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541792/how-to-parse-raw-mime-content-in-java

Comment: you mean downloading mail with EWS and parsing content with java mail? I was searching a solution in EWS api.

Comment: There is nothing in the EWS that will parse Mime content you will need to use another library to do that