# Download a file with no extension from a server

Tags: android, url, download, mp3

I'm try to download a mp3 file from following URL. I found lot of articles and examples regarding file download. Those examples are based on URLs that end with a file extension, e.g.:- `yourdomain.com/filename.mp3` but I want to download a file from following url which typically does not end with file extension.

`youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=1gsE32jF0aVaY0smDVf%2BmwnIZPrMDnGmchHBu0Hovd3Hl4NYqjNdym4RqjDSAis7p1n5O%2BeXmdwFxK9ugErLWQ%3D%3D`

**Please note that I use the above url as-is without using Stackoverflow url formatting method to easily understand the question.

** **I have tried the @Arsal Imam's solution as follows still not working**

```
   btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // starting new Async Task
            File cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Folder Name");
            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();

            File f=new File(cacheDir,"ddedddddd.mp3");
            saveDir=f.getPath();

            new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(fileURL);
        }
    });
```

and the async task code is as follows

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        try{

            URL url = new URL(fileURL);
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            // always check HTTP response code first
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String fileName = "";
                String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
                int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

                if (disposition != null) {
                    // extracts file name from header field
                    int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                    if (index > 0) {
                        fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                                disposition.length() - 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    // extracts file name from URL
                    fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                            fileURL.length());
                }

                System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
                System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
                System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
                System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

                // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
                InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

                // opens an output stream to save into file
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveDir);

                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();

                System.out.println("File downloaded");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
            }
            httpConn.disconnect();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. Did you know in advance the extension of the file?

Comment: its a mp3 file. I'm trying it from `youtubeinmp3.com/api` to get the mp3 version of a youtube api. this url works fine when copy paste it into browser url. but I need to download it from android application

Comment: Try to get the MIME type of the response dynamically. This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077933/how-to-find-mimetype-of-response) might help you.

Comment: How do you download the file from a browser? Just pasting the `URL` isn't enough - you also have to press the `DOWNLOAD` button, isn't it?

Comment: no.. I have taken the link from the following location. `http://youtubeinmp3.com/api/` once you go to this url, you can get the file download url

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although [**Volley** library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) is not recommended for large download or streaming operations, however, I'd like to share my following working sample code.

Let's assume we download only **MP3** files so I hard-code the extension. And of course, we should check more carefully to avoid exceptions (NullPointer...) such as checking whether headers contain `"Content-Disposition"` key or not...

Hope this helps!

**Volley Custom class:**

```
public class BaseVolleyRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {

    private final Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private final Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public BaseVolleyRequest(String url, Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(0, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
        return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }
}
```

**Then in your Activity:**

```
public class BinaryVolleyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Context mContext = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_binary_volley);
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        String url = "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=3sI2yV5mJ0kQ8CnddqmANZqK8a%2BgVQJ%2Fmg3xwhHTUsJKuusOCZUzebuWW%2BJSFs0oz8VTs6ES3gjohKQMogixlQ%3D%3D";
        BaseVolleyRequest volleyRequest = new BaseVolleyRequest(url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {                    
                Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;
                String contentDisposition = headers.get("Content-Disposition");
                // String contentType = headers.get("Content-Type");
                String[] temp = contentDisposition.split("filename=");
                String fileName = temp[1].replace("\"", "") + ".mp3";
                InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.data);
                createLocalFile(inputStream, fileName);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            }
        });

        volleyRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        requestQueue.add(volleyRequest);
    }

    private String createLocalFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) {
        try {
            String folderName = "MP3VOLLEY";
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, folderName);
            folder.mkdir();
            File file = new File(folder, fileName);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            //f.flush();
            f.close();
            return file.getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the result screenshot:

[image: Volley download file]

**NOTE:**

As I commented below, because the direct download Url changes regularly, you should check the new url with some tools such as [Postman for Chrome](https://www.getpostman.com/), if it responses binary instead of a web page (expired url), then the Url is valid and my code works for that Url.

Refer to the two following screenshots:

Expired url:

[image: Expired url]

Un-expired url:

[image: Un-expired url]

**UPDATE BASIC LOGIC FOR GETTING DIRECT DOWNLOAD LINK FROM THAT SITE'S DOCUMENTATION:**

According to [Create Your Own YouTube To MP3 Downloader For Free](http://youtubeinmp3.com/api/)

You can take a look at

> JSON Example
>
> You can also receive the data in JSON by setting the "format"
>   parameter to "JSON".
>   http://YouTubeInMP3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM

Firstly, you create a `JsonObjectRequest` getting response from the above file link. Then, inside `onResponse` of this `JsonObjectRequest` you will get the direct download link, like this `directUrl = response.getString("link");` and use `BaseVolleyRequest volleyRequest`

I have just told the logic for getting direct url, IMO, you should implement it yourself. Goodluck!

Comment: this is not worked for me.. I've tried. It always throws a null pointer exceptions at `String[] temp = contentDisposition.split("filename=");` this line.because `contentDisposition` variable is `null`

Comment: Have you tried with my Url? That the real Url that you can test with Postman in Chrome :)

Comment: Ah, It just changes to `http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=3sI2yV5mJ0kQ8CnddqmANZqK8a%2BgVQJ%2Fmg3xwhHTUsJ%2FbBwmWleQv4tIX9bc9BcLLp0SkvyuiKstwTjkHhSxvA%3D%3D`

Comment: only 5 hours to offer the bounty, can you plz check this.

Comment: I think the server youtubeinmp3.com generates the real (exact) url for downloading MP3 for dynamic session, I mean that the value after `?i=` with change for each time we visit

Comment: I have just downloaded that mp3 file with the new Url `String url = "http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=3sI2yV5mJ0kQ8CnddqmANZqK8a%2BgVQJ%2Fmg3xwhHTUsJ%2FbBwmWleQv4tIX9bc9BcLLp0SkvyuiKstwTjkHhSxvA%3D%3D";`

Comment: it's not working for me.. can you please send me the project file. `dehanpramoda@outlook.com`

Comment: Please do the following steps: 1. Open browser, such as Chrome to get the real download Url (for example by right click Download MP3 button). Then, paste that Url into your Android app and run. Do this, if still not working, I will send you

Comment: its appreciate if you can send the code or share it via a link

Comment: I uploaded sample code to [GitHub](https://github.com/ngocchung/googlevolley). However, as I mentioned, the real download Url changed regularly, so you need to get it as the above steps (I found that in your comments in your questions, you said you get the download link from .../api...)

Comment: still not working, it gives same null pointer exception.
i'm using the `http://YouTubeInMP3.com/fetch/?format=text&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM` this link to get the download URL. once you click on above url it will give you the download url. i guess you get the URL same way.

Comment: No, I paste the old direct Url (`http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=3sI2yV5mJ0kQ8CnddqmANZqK8a%2BgVQJ%2‌​Fmg3xwhHTUsJ%2FbBwmWleQv4tIX9bc9BcLLp0SkvyuiKstwTjkHhSxvA%3D%3D`), then it redirects me to the new page, click on Download MP3 to go to a new page, at which right click on Download MP3 button to copy a new direct working download link

Comment: With a new download link, you can use Postman add-in in Chrome to test if it can be downloaded or not

Comment: not working even with new urls, it always throws nullpointer exceptions

Comment: As I said, try the new url with Postman, if it responses binary instead of a web page (expired url), then the Url is valid and my code works for that Url.

Comment: Please google for Postman, I am online in mobile so cannot help. Postman is for Chrome, not for Android

Comment: Hi! Pls take a look at my updated answer (`UPDATE BASIC LOGIC FOR GETTING DIRECT DOWNLOAD LINK FROM THAT SITE'S DOCUMENTATION`)

Comment: @BNK, I have downloaded mp3 file by using your reference but the problem is the downloaded mp3 file is not playing. What is the problem ?please help me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Naveen perhaps the files you downloaded have problems? I have just tested my code again, the MP3 file "Happy..." can be played well

Comment: @BNK, Thanks for the response.Issue was the file in the server was corrupted. Resovled now.Thank you BNK.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code it works fine for encrypted URLs

```
public class HttpDownloadUtility {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    /**
     * Downloads a file from a URL
     * @param fileURL HTTP URL of the file to be downloaded
     * @param saveDir path of the directory to save the file
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }

            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: when the download url copy paste to the browser address bar.. its downloading.. but not working this way

Answer (score 0):

The url returns a 302 redirect to the actual .mp3. The browser does the redirect in the background for you, but in your app you need to do it yourself. Here is an example on how to do that with HttpUrlConnection http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the type of file in advance then you can download your file from url which don't have extension.

DownloadService .java

```
public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;
    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String filename;
    File mypath;
    String urlToDownload;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcaster;
    Intent intent1;
    static final public String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.example.app.activity.test.broadcast";
    public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");   
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        intent1 = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        ResultReceiver receiver = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        try {
            intent1 = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
            urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
            filename= intent.getStringExtra("filename");

            BufferedWriter out;
            try {
                File path=new File("/sdcard/","folder name");
                path.mkdir();
                mypath=new File(path,filename);
                Log.e("mypath",""+mypath);
                if (!mypath.exists()) {
                    out= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(mypath));
                    //ut = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput( mypath.getAbsolutePath() ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
                    out.write("test");
                    out.close();

                } 

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
                resultData.putInt("progress" ,(int) (total * 100 / fileLength));


                //Log.e("mypath",""+mypath);
                resultData.putString("mypath", ""+mypath);
                receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);         

                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bundle resultData = new Bundle();
        resultData.putInt("progress" ,100);
        resultData.putString("mypath", ""+mypath);
        receiver.send(UPDATE_PROGRESS, resultData);
        intent1.putExtra("progressbar", 100);
        sendBroadcast(intent1);
    }
}
```

DownloadReceiver.java

```
public class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver{

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String filename;

    String mypath;
    public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler ,String filename ,Context context) {
        super(handler);

    this.context = context;
        this.filename = filename;

        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
            int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
            mypath = resultData.getString("mypath");
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress);
            //Log.e("progress","progress");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("App name");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            if (progress == 100) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("download","download");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now start service in your mainactivity by below code :

```
Intent miIntent = new Intent(mContext, DownloadService.class);
                            miIntent.putExtra("url", url);
                            miIntent.putExtra("filename", id+".mp3");

                            miIntent.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler() , id,mContext));
                            startService(miIntent);
```