# How to parse different http content-type using only JavaSE tools?

Tags: java, http, parsing, inputstream

How can I parse multipart/form-data request using only JavaSE? For example, when i got such HTTP request:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-agent: Agent\r\n
Content-type:  multipart/form-data; boundary= qwertyuiop\r\n
Content-Length: \ r\n
\r\n
-- qwertyuiop\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”file”; filename=”1.bmp”\r\n
\r\n
…………………………..-bytes
-- qwertyuiop\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”text”\r\n
\r\n
Some -text
-- qwertyuiop—
\r\n
```

What is the alghorithm of parsing here? When I am reading headers, I read Strings or char's, but when I am reading file, I read bytes. I have to swap readers when they get the boundary, but how reader that reading bytes can find the boundary? Only one idea I have, is to use Content-length parameter in the Content-Disposition of each part. But there no such parameter in the HTTP multipart/form-data.
What is the algorithm of parsing using only JavaSE? Help me please

Comment: The Java Servlet technology is built to do this for you. Why not use it?

Comment: Are you using CXF with Java SE, then you can use the object org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment

Comment: I sure that it is possible to do in clean JavaSE. So, I am trying to find a way how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find mimetype of response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077933/how-to-find-mimetype-of-response)